# golang http disable TRACE method

Tags: go, go-http

Is there something like the `traceEnable` parameter in apache, in golang net/http?

I do have something like the following, but I do want to listen to `GET`, `POST` and `HEAD`, however not to the `TRACE` method

```
go func() {
        logger.Log(
            "level", 1,
            "action", "start https",
            "addr", opts.httpsAddr,
        )

        s := &http.Server{
            Addr:    opts.httpsAddr,
            Handler: server,
            TLSConfig: &tls.Config{
                MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12,
            },
        }
        http2.ConfigureServer(s, nil)

        fatal("failed to start HTTPS: %s", s.ListenAndServeTLS(opts.tlsCrt, opts.tlsKey))
    }()
```

Basically I'd like to return a 405 on such a request

```
curl -v -X TRACE https://<server>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something like the traceEnable parameter in apache, in golang net/http?

No.

You have to do that in your handler or middleware.